# How to extract multiple numerical values in the middle of a text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I would like to extract the numerical values in the middle of a cell and have it in separate columns. There are usually two numbers between the texts, and I would like to have them separated such as table 3 below. If there is only one value, it would go to the "From" Column.

I am currently using the delimiter and separating each of the texts by space or by "-". It worked to a certain extent except that some of the columns with the numerical values contained text as well as seen in table 2. The sample data is in Table 1.

I tried using the LEFT function, but I don't think I'm using it correctly. Is there a way to get it to look like Table 3?

Thank you!

Table 1. Sample data

| Name |
| --- |
| abcd 29.1 42.3 (1PRO) |
| 620001 T abcd 32.6 41 (3ea) |
| 600121 abcd cross 74.0 (Crea) |

Table 2.

| Name |  | From | To |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd 29.1 42.3 (1PRO) | abcd | 29.1 | 42.3 | (1PRO) |  |  |
| 620001 T abcd 32.6 41 (3ea) | 620001 | T | abcd | 32.6 | 41 | (3ea) |
| 600121 abcd cross 74.0 (Crea) | 600121 | abcd | cross | 74.0 | (crea) |  |

Table 3.

| Name | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd 29.1 42.3 (1PRO) | 29.1 | 42.3 |
| 620001 T abcd 32.6 41 (3ea) | 32.6 | 41 |
| 600121 abcd cross 74.0 (Crea) | 74.0 |  |

Comment: You could work your way around this issue with FILTERXML if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Excel 2016, you can use the `FILTERXML` function and an `xPath` argument that returns only numeric values excluding the first node.

- Construct XML:
  `"<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A21," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>"`
- the `xPath`:
  `"//s[position()>1 and number(.)=number(.)]"`

If you had dynamic arrays, that would be all you need.  But since you don't you need to wrap into an `INDEX` function to extract the individual elements.

If there are at most, two elements, you can hard code the "row" entry; if not, you will need to use a dynamic function to generate the rows.

Below I show the dynamic function which will increment by one for each column you "drag" the formula to the right.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[position()>1 and number(.)=number(.)]"),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always solve this sort of issue by doing the following.

Create a custom function with the following code in a new module.

If you've never done that before, then follow this link ... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f ... and open the section "Creating a simple custom function"

```
Public Function SplitString(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strDelimiter As String, ByVal lngIndex As Long) As String
    Dim arrSplitString
    
    arrSplitString = Split(strText, strDelimiter)
    
    If UBound(arrSplitString) >= lngIndex Then
        SplitString = arrSplitString(lngIndex)
    End If
End Function
```

Then add your formula in as shown below taking note that arrays start from 0.

[image]

Voila!  I hope that helps.